# How do I import data but stop importing when a blank cell is found

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, range, spreadsheet, min

I want to be able to import data but only to the blank cell
How would I do this?

Instead of just ignoring the cell and carrying on I would simply like it to stop

Like this if Row C was the imported data

Sheet with an example of how it'd work

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MIN(IFERROR(1/1/(A1:A="")*(ROW(A1:A))))-1))
```

[image]